# Angular Material Drag and drop + scroll

Tags: angular, angular-material

I using Angular Material (Angular 9.1.2, Material 9.2.1).

I have scrollable container and drag-drop lists (multiple lists) inside. In Mateiral v9 they add function to fix placeholder and sorting position **withScrollableParents()**. And it's setting properly, but... it's works only after sorting, draging or droping item on list. On first event after comonent init it doesn't. Any idea what I done wrong? Or I should create issue for Angular material?

```js
  @ViewChildren(CdkDropList) dropLists: QueryList<CdkDropList>;

  protected setScrollContainer() {
    if (this.dropLists) {
      this.dropLists.forEach((x) => {
        const htmlElement = x.element.nativeElement;
        const scrolledElement = htmlElement.closest('.ps.ps--active-y') as HTMLElement;

        x._dropListRef.withScrollableParents([scrolledElement]);
      });
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="fields-list"
     cdkDropList
     #list2
     (mouseenter)="setScrollContainer()"
     [id]="addFiltersId(groupIndex, 'report-where')"
     [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="dragAndDropListsFilters"
     [cdkDropListData]="filtersGroup.filter"
     (cdkDropListDropped)="dropFilter($event, 0)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `cdkScrollable` to the HTML element you want to be scrollable.